# Grading program in python, stuck on if else statements

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm still pretty new to python, and I have to write this program where the user enters homework grades, types 'done' and gets their grades back.  I'm almost done with it, but I keep getting error messages when it gets to the loop:

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int().

```
print("Enter the homework scores one at a time. Type 'done' when done")
hwCount = 1
totalScore = 0
strScore = input("Enter the HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
while strScore != "done":
    if ( strScore is int and strScore >= 0 and strScore <= 10 ):
        totalScore = totalScore + strScore
        hwCount = hwCount + 1
    elif ( strScore is int and strScore < 0 or strScore > 10):
    print("Please enter a number between 0 and 10")
    else:
        print("Please enter only whole numbers")
    strScore = input("Enter HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
```

I tried this:

```
strScore = int(input("Enter the HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
```

but it would only print the else statement, and then I got the same error as before. If someone could help me figure this out I'd really appreciate it

Comment: You __are__ comparing a string with a int.

Comment: in the first `if` statement you are comparing `strScore` which is a string to 0 and 10. The `TypeError` tells you that it can't compare/order string and int

Comment: (my apologies; this code **will** do the `>` comparison despite the `strScore is int` being completely wrong because you've also mixed the the precedence of `and` and `or`.)

Comment: Aside: `input()` returns a string, always (in Python 3). You can't just ask `is it an int?`, even if it is a string of digits and looks like a number, that will always fail. You have to forcibly convert it to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strScore` is a string. Your `while` loop should look like this:

```
while strScore != "done":
    try:
        score = int(strScore)
        if score >= 0 and score <= 10:
            totalScore = totalScore + score
            hwCount = hwCount + 1
        else:
            print("Please enter a number between 0 and 10")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter only whole numbers or 'done'")
    strScore = input("Enter HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
```

As you show in your code, there are three cases to handle - user enters a valid score, user enters a valid number but invalid score, and user enters an invalid number. If the user enters an invalid integer, trying `int(strScore)` will raise a `ValueError`, which we can catch and report. Knowing that otherwise `score` will be a valid `int`, we only have to check if it is a valid score or not, allowing you to change the `elif` into a simple `else`.

Comment: Not that Hungarian notation is a good idea anyway, but calling an `int` `strScore` seems like a bad idea ;)

Comment: @Wooble >:( I was just about to write that!!~

Comment: @Wooble Good point - might as well help a little with good naming conventions while we're at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
strScore = int(input("Enter the HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
```

won't work because you have

```
while strScore != 'done':
```

which requires `strScore` to be a string (eventually). See the Rob Watts' answer for the code (beaten me to it)

Answer (score 0):

input (python3) always returns a str.  You need to convert it for integer comparison and adding.  I like to break my valid input logic from my other work, so if you define function like this(hopefully reusable):

```
def get_valid_input(prompt, min_score=0, max_score=10):
   while True:
        text = input(prompt).strip()
        if text == 'done':
            return text
        try:
            score = int(text)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number or done")
            continue
        if min_score <= score <= max_score:
            return score
        else:
            print("Please enter a number between %s and %s" % (min_score, max_score))
```

then to get your HW scores, its a simple matter

```
total_score = 0
hw_count = 1
score = get_valid_input("Enter HW#%s score: " % hw_count)
while score != "done":
    total_score += score
    hw_count += 1
    score = get_valid_input("Enter HW#%s score: " % hw_count)
```